# android textview baseline superscript underscript

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I'm new to android and i'm developing an app to generate musical notes based on user input. I have read related posts talking about adding underline to textview. For my app, certain notes(which are numbers) in textview need to have single underline, some need to have double underline and some need dot under them or even curve upon them.

[example of the notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GFSn.png)

I have been thinking of using similar utf-8 but haven't found numbers with such underlines and frown or arc tie.

So far people use Office Word equation to generate and edit such notes. I am not sure what's the best way to display it in android textview or giving the number with their subscript and subscript sign. Later on we even want to allow user to edit the notes.

Any idea of how to display numbers with superscript/subscript in textview?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For one possibility, you can check out one of my answers here:  [Drawing an image above an android text span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367961/drawing-an-image-above-an-android-text-span/34377864#34377864)

However, in your case I would just have a custom view for the entire staff, develop a data structure for where all the numbers and symbols go, override `onDraw()` and render them into the view canvas directly.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of notation is this?  I'm also a musician and I've never really seen this before.

Comment: Thanks! Kris. it is called numeric musical notation. Just now i found that i can use sub/superscript provided by unicode directly, but still dont know how with the different size of curves and ties. Thanks for your answer.[link](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf)